# PHP form generating blank emails

Tags: php, forms

I've found a lot of threads outlining similar issues as this, but the code always looked a bit different and each solution was vastly different, so as someone who is pretty green to the PHP world, I would really appreciate some extra help here!

We have landing pages with lead forms on them. Most of the time they work and there's a system in place to keep blank submissions, or submissions missing required fields, from submitting. However, we've been getting strings of completely blank emails from these forms-- usually in bursts of two at exactly the same time, but not always. I do not think that someone is pressing the submit button without filling out fields because I've tested this many times and nothing has ever come through. I know enough PHP to generally recognize what I'm looking at, but I have very little experience writing things from scratch, and these forms were made by the person that held my position before me, so it's possible they're messed up in some fundamental way and I just didn't recognize it because of my limited PHP experience.

Here's the html for the form section of our page:

```
<form method="post" name="form-name" id="form-name" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="PIN" name="PIN"/>


        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="lettersonly" id="firstname"  placeholder="First Name" value="" required />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="lettersonly" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required />


        <input type="email" name="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="" required />

        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="digits" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="" required />

        <input type="text" name="zipcode" class="digits" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" value="" required />

    <?php echo $errorString; ?>

    <div id="submit_buttons">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-form" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

ANd here is our entire process.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$allowedFields = array(
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'zipcode',
);

$requiredFields = array(
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'zipcode',
);

$requiredEmail = array(
    'email',
);

$errors = array();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
    // first need to make sure this is an allowed field
    if(in_array($key, $allowedFields))
    {
        $$key = $value;

        // is this a required field?
        if(in_array($key, $requiredFields) && $value == '') 
        {
            $errors[] = "The field $key is required.";
        }

        // is this a required field?
        if(in_array($key, $requiredEmail) && !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))    
        {
            $errors[] = "A valid email is required.";
        }
    }   
}

// were there any errors?
if(count($errors) > 0)
{
    $errorString = '<div class="error2"><h1>There was an error with the form.</h1><br />';
    $errorString .= '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
        $errorString .= "<li>$error</li>";
    }
    $errorString .= '</ul></div>';

    // display the previous form
    include 'index.php';
}
else
{

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; } 
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; } 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; } 
if(isset($_POST['phone'])){ $phone = $_POST['phone']; } 
if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){ $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode']; } 

$formcontent = "$firstname $lastname \r\n$email \r\n$phone \r\n$zipcode \r\n";;

    // toggle this line on or off for testing with '//'  
//$recipient = "<ben@plumdm.com>";

    // change emails
$recipient = "Web Dev <developer@site.com>";

    // change subject line number
$subject = "getmyreport.org/001 - Landing Page Lead";

$mailheader = "Landing Page <landings@plumdm.com>";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

    // change url number
header("Location: http://www.getmyreport.org/thanks.html");
}
```

I did make a change in this based on what I've read here in other similar threads, but it doesn't seem to have worked. I changed this original code:

```
$_POST['firstname'])){ $name = $_POST['firstname'];
```

to this, which is in the current code above:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $name = $_POST['firstname']; }
```

It worked for the poster of the other similar post, but I'm still getting blank emails.

I also noticed that in the error_log file, there are entries corresponding to the arrival of the blank emails that look like this:

```
[04-Apr-2014 10:49:22 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: firstname in /home3/plumdmco/public_html/getmyreport/001/process.php on line 69
[04-Apr-2014 10:49:22 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: lastname in /home3/plumdmco/public_html/getmyreport/001/process.php on line 69
[04-Apr-2014 10:49:22 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: email in /home3/plumdmco/public_html/getmyreport/001/process.php on line 69
[04-Apr-2014 10:49:22 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: phone in /home3/plumdmco/public_html/getmyreport/001/process.php on line 69
[04-Apr-2014 10:49:22 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: zipcode in /home3/plumdmco/public_html/getmyreport/001/process.php on line 69
```

I'm really stumped on this one and hours of research hasn't gotten me anywhere. I'd really appreciate some help if anyone can offer it! Thanks!

EDIT - A lot of your are mentioning the mismatched variables-- my mistake, I copied the in-progress file I had saved instead of the currently active one. Fixed now. Sorry!

Comment: `$price = $_POST['lastname'];` --- `$price = $_POST['email'];` double check all your variables. Those findings are based on spending 5 seconds looking through your code. I'm sure I could find more, but that's "your" job.

Comment: What he said, also this one, which is probably why you have a blank email: if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $price = $_POST['email']; }

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about un-matched and duplicated variables.

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally copy/pasted an in-progress version of the code instead of the version that was actually finished and online. I edited my post with the correct version. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I believe what's happening is that users are going directly to `process.php` somehow. This will trigger an email even though the POST array is empty, and thus produce an empty email. Since the POST array is empty, you get those undefined variable notices. To avoid this, you can wrap all of the code in `process.php` in an if block.

If someone accesses the page directly, the SERVER request method will be `GET`. Instead of sending the email, this will redirect users to the form page.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $allowedFields = array(
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'zipcode',
    );

    //same, same, same, all the way down to

    // change url number
    header("Location: http://www.getmyreport.org/thanks.html");
    }

} else {

    header("Location: index.php");

}
```

Also, this line has two semicolons:

```
$formcontent = "$firstname $lastname \r\n$email \r\n$phone \r\n$zipcode \r\n";;  //;;
```

Comment: My mistake, I copy pasted an in progross copy of the code I had saved instead of the actual active version. I edited my original post, where the variables are matched up correctly. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you are handling the validation of form fields. If someone wrote a script that posted to this page and they didn't pass any `$_POST` values, you would essentially loop over an empty `$_POST` array which means you would loop zero times. Nothing would get validated because all validation is done within that loop and `count($errors)` would be zero.

You also need loop over the `$requiredFields` array at some point and make sure that each of those fields exists in `$_POST`.

This would also account for the errors you are seeing. The variables don't exist in $_POST and so `isset($_POST['...'])` returns false, the variable isn't being set, but it is being used when building the body of the email.